# Content(php code) Download from apache directory list

Tags: php, apache

I have to download .php file with php source code from a apache directory listing page. can anybody have such idea or experience????

Answer (score 1):

You can either rename the file by choosing a different extension.

Or, you can remove the `AddType` attribute in `IfModule` related to your directory that defined `.php` extension.

Comment: Actually i have no access to the server. thats why i can't change the extension and can't change the AddType.

Answer (score 0):

You could use https://www.php.net/highlight_file to set up a specific file that can print out the source for any file. If you look at the description section it also talks about how you can setup your server to automatically display the source if you have a file named .phps.

You should be able to figure out a solution that works for you with something like this.

If you absolutely need the file to download and not just display the source you could create a script that reads the file and presents it to the user as a plain text file download. That could be accomplished with a combination of http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score -1):

You need to stream the file contents through another script:

download-file.php

```
<?php

$file = '/path/to/php-file.php';

header('Content-Type: application/x-httpd-php');
header(sprintf('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=%s', basename($file)));

readfile($file);
```

Comment: Using this method has only ever brought me blank files, where navigating to the same location in-browser provides at least some (albeit processed) content